# java udp server 100% cpu

Tags: java, performance, server, udp

I have a UDP server that receives packets at 40 pkts per seconds.
The main loop is below:

```
 public void serve() {
        while(true) {
              ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
              bytes.clear();
              channel.receive(bytes);
              THandler th = new THandler(bytes);
              th.start();
        }
    }
```

Channel Initialization:

```
private final DatagramChannel channel ;  
channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

The class THandler extends a thread class and it filters the message against a regular expression and then finds an id from the matching message.
This id is then compared to a list of subscribers (approx 300k). followed by a db select followed by an update.

```
public void run() {

    if (!this.isValidLog()){ //does a regular expression match
        return;
    }
    String subsId = this.getSubscriberId(); // extracts the id from message
    if (this.isServiceSubscribed(subsId)) { // compares in a list of subscribers

        usageDetails = this.getServiceUsage(subsId); // db Query
        if(usageDetails.isFeatureAvailable()){
            usageDetails.updateUsageCounter(); // db Update
        }
    }


}
```

I have tried using ExecutorService also.  But the problem is that I run out of CPU time with 99.6% or more in user.

Any inputs on how to improve the performance of the server and code are most welcome.

Comment: It doesn't look like a matter of performance, while(true) { is a busy loop that will indeed eat up 100% of a cpu if there is nothing in there that will put the logic to rest for a period of time. As a test, try adding a Thread.sleep(1) in that busy loop to see how that influences the CPU usage.

Comment: Please show the code that you use to prepare the `channel`.

Comment: It seems like you need to profile your code. This can be done with `jvisualvm` that comes with your JDK. @EJP has a great answer otherwise

Comment: I suggest you use a cached Thread Pool i.e. ExecutorService instead of creating a Thread for each packet.  Creating a Thread is very expensive, and you might find the pool is rarely more than one thread in it.

Comment: You only need to clear a ByteBuffer if you are re-using it. A new ByteBuffer is always `clear()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure the channel is in blocking mode.
- You don't need to clear a newly created `ByteBuffer.`
- Use an `ExecutorService` with a reasonably sized thread pool, instead of creating a new thread per datagram.
- Ensure you are using O(1) data structures.
- Combine the database lookup and update into one operation, using `UPDATE ... WHERE`, and get the update count if you need to see whether anything happened.
- Ignore any suggestion to add sleeps into networking code. They are literally a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your search is simply iteration through an array. You might want to replace these with a more efficient method.

Have a look at the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) specially [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: I tried by pruning the list to only one subscriber, but to no avail, CPU still 100% occupied.

Comment: In that case the DatagramChannel might not be in blocking mode as @EJP mentioned is his answer. My suspicion was that the data handling/searching took up all the CPU.